# Guid.ParseExact throws FormatException C# hexadecimal

Tags: c#, guid

I am unable to create a new Guid by using `Guid.parse` or `Guid.parseExact` using the below formatting in C#. What is the right formatting for `Guid.parseExact` for a hexadecimal? (I actually haven't seen a working "format" implementation on the web yet for hexadecimal value in the below format)

Or, is there a GUID converter? So that I can convert formats like this to "regular" decimal format and parse easier?

GUID IS `{{0x1790c9ecL,0x47d5,0x4df3,{{0xb5,0xaf,0x9a,0xdf,0x3c,0xf2,0x3e,0x48}}}}`

```
Guid DEVINTERFACE = Guid.ParseExact(
    "{{0x4390c9ecL,0x4125,0x45f3,{{0x55,0xbf,0x9a,0xdf,0x3c,0x42,0x4e,0x42}}}}",
    "X");
```

Comment: I'll be honest with you: not once **ever**, before today, have I seen anyone actually use the `"X"` format. I am very curious *why exactly* you have chosen this...

Comment: Being forced to Use the "X" format as that is how I am being fed the GUIDs.

Comment: But you aren't actually using the "X" format anyway! You are using something similar, with twice as many braces and some trailing Ls. You might need to run it through a regex or similar

Answer (score 4):

Too many braces:

```
var g = Guid.ParseExact(
    "{0x1790c9ec,0x47d5,0x4df3,{0xb5,0xaf,0x9a,0xdf,0x3c,0xf2,0x3e,0x48}}", "X");
```

Note that if you do:

```
string s = g.ToString("X");
```

then you get back what you started with:

```
"{0x1790c9ec,0x47d5,0x4df3,{0xb5,0xaf,0x9a,0xdf,0x3c,0xf2,0x3e,0x48}}"
```

Basically, your understanding of the `"X"` format is incorrect.

Although personally, I'd strongly suggest the more normal representations:

```
"1790c9ec-47d5-4df3-b5af-9adf3cf23e48" // format "D"
```

or:

```
"1790c9ec47d54df3b5af9adf3cf23e48" // format "N"
```

> OR is there a GUID converter? So that I can convert formats like this to "regular" decimal format and parse easier?

Guids are virtually never shown in decimal format; the only difference here is the braces, the commas, the dashes, and the leading `0x` prefixes. The data in all of the `Guid` formats in .NET is hexadecimal.

Comment: I have tried 1/2 Braces
"{0x1790c9ec,0x47d5,0x4df3,{0xb5,0xaf,0x9a,0xdf,0x3c,0xf2,0x3e,0x48}}"
2/4 braces
"{{0x1790c9ec,0x47d5,0x4df3,{{0xb5,0xaf,0x9a,0xdf,0x3c,0xf2,0x3e,0x48}}}}"

Still getting the format exception.. Funnily,I am not even able step into the GUID.cs code.

Comment: @Comedian Did you remove the Ls ? Because that first line "I have tried 1/2 Braces" - that works perfectly. Try it.

Comment: Oh, can't belive i made that error.. Dint see that I had an 'L'.. It works perfectly now. thanks!

Comment: You'd be amazed how often it does :)  Hex is meant for strings.  So is L, it makes it a wide string literal in C or C++.